# c++ derived class access through linkedlist

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to write a program that has one base class (Employee), and two derived classes (Staff and Manager).
I'm storing the data in a Linked List.

Upon attempting to access a function to Manager I've run into problems due to what I believe is downcasting?
When receiving the data from the linked list for the node, it assumes its of type Employee - where as I need it to be of type Manager to access the private function. 
I've attempted to upcast it however it doesn't like how i'm using the variables.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue and enable access to the functions within my derived classes?
 Please note i'm very new to this so please bare that in mind if I've made an obvious mistake please!

```
void displayManagerDetails(const List<Employee*> list)
{
    unsigned long longID = getID();
    List<Employee*> temp(list);
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Name         Department      Salary\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    while (!temp.isEmpty())
    {
        if (temp.first().data->getEmpNo() == longID && temp.first().data->getType() == "Manager")
        {       
            Manager hold = temp.first();
            Employee* pEmp = &hold;
            Manager* test = dynamic_cast<Manager*>(pEmp);

            cout << test->getSalary()


            return;
        }
        temp.deleteFirst();
    }
}
```

If you need further code please let me know however I thought this is all that is relevant :)

Comment: You probably want to have something like [`List<std::unique_ptr<Employee>>`, `List<std:weak_ptr<Employee>>`, or `List<std::shared_ptr<Employee>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to handle your use case correctly.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: If it is a private function, how do you expect to have access outside the class?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis I have a linkedlist of stored Staff and Manager objects - which I am calling functions on. However when I attempt to get the object back (in the code shown above) and access its getSalary function, it won't let me - I can only access the base classes functions

Comment: You can't access private methods outside of the class for which they are defined. Make those methods public then try.

Comment: Is getSalary under a public: section in your class definition?

Comment: Apologies I just realised that I was explaining that wrong - you are correct. getSalary is a public function in my derived class

Comment: However, I still can't access that function as the code shown above still thinks that i'm accessing a Employee class rather than a Manager class which it should be!

Comment: I am not sure what your List or your class are defined (you should give the pertinent information).  But Manager hold = temp.first() seems incorrect based on context clues.  Why not Manager * test = dynamic_cast< Manager * >( temp.first().data );

Comment: It might be helpful if you post class headers for Manager and Employee. Also, do you get any compile or run-time errors?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis That line of code you posted worked! Thank you very much - sorry about the vagueness of my question and explaination! If you'd like to post that as an answer, i'l select that for your +rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be extracting your pointer from the linked list incorrectly based on other usage in your code.  Try:

```
Manager * test = dynamic_cast< Manager * >( temp.first().data );
```